# Return array with duplicated elements only N times maximum for duplicated elements ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I return array with duplicated elements from given `array` that contains each number of duplicated elements only `max_elements` times without reordering.

```
def delete_nth_elements(array,max_elements)
  #your code here
end

delete_nth_elements([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,6],2) # return [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,6]
```

and drop the next [1,2,3] since this would lead to 1 2 and 3 being in the result 3 times.

Comment: @EliSadoff I tried the method uniq and its attributes but, unfortunately, it does not give me a good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def delete_nth_elements(arr, max_elements)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  arr.select { |e| (h[e] += 1) <= max_elements}   
end

delete_nth_elements([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,6],2)
  #=> [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,6]
```

`h` is often called a *counting hash*. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), particularly in reference to the default value (here `0`). One could instead write

```
def delete_nth_elements(arr, max_elements)
  h = {}
  arr.select { |e| (h[e] ||= 0) += 1) <= max_elements}   
end
```

`h[e] ||= 0) += 1` expands to

```
(h[e] = h[e] || 0) += 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `e`, `h[e] #=> nil`, so the above expression reduces to

```
h[e] = 0 + 1
  #=> 1
```